# How to convert a very large Json Array into CSV string?

Tags: json, csv

I have a problem when converting the Json array into csv string by using CDL. I am getting an exception **"StringIndexOutOfBoundsException : String index out of range"** .

Note: I am using a very large Json data for this. Each object contains some 100 name:value pairs.

The code snippet of the conversion part is this.

```
// Get JSON data
        String jsonString = "{\"infile\":" + output + "}";
        try {
        JSONObject jsonOut = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray docs = jsonOut.getJSONArray("infile");

        // Parse JSON to CSV 
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/jsonTocsv.csv";
//        File file=new File("C:/Users/dasswati/Documents/fromJSON.csv");
        File file = new File(filePath);
        **String csv = CDL.toString(docs);**// here is the part I am getting the error.
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }


     // return response
        writer.println(htmlRespone);

               }
```

String csv = CDL.toString(docs) is where I am getting the error.

Can u suggest me any other way of converting or any other suggestions are also welcome.